# Next & Previous files

Tags: assets

I am using assets for a photo gallery site.

The first page shows the list of images as thumbnails, when you click a thumbnail it loads a page where it just shows the single image (passing the file_id through segment_4).

What I want to do make the large image on this page clickable to go to the next image on it's own page (unique URL).

Can someone tell me if this is possible and if so how i should go about it.

big thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to do this? One entry per file? Channel:entries? Files:entries?

Comment: @RobsonSobral - I am using a channel field. I have tried using the following code but for some reason the offset="1" does not work. 

<a href="/{segment_1}/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/{photo_gallery offset="1" limit="1" file_id="{segment_4}"}{file_id}{/photo_gallery}">{photo_gallery limit="1" file_id="{segment_4}"}{exp:ce_img:single src="{url}" width="960" quality="95" crop="yes" cache="yes" filter="auto_sharpen"}{/photo_gallery}</a>

Comment: The `offset` parameter skips the first `X` files. I don't have Assets to test out, but does the `{count}` parameter work within the `{photo_gallery}` tag pair?

Comment: yeah i get how the offset works but it just seems to fail in this case. I might have to hit support direct to see if it is a bug. thanks for taking the time to try and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Will Hunting](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/will-hunting) plugin to do simple math to increment/decrement the next/prev links based off `{segment_4}`:

```
<a href="{exp:will_hunting:solve exp="{segment_4} - 1"}">prev page</a>
<a href="{exp:will_hunting:solve exp="{segment_4} + 1"}">next page</a>
```

Comment: the only problem with your solution is what if the file id is not always in the continues number order, ie the post could contain images from different folders and in different orders

Comment: That was never mentioned, but a valid point.

Comment: Your answer actually ended up being the way to go but because the offset doesn't work with a single use of file_id (coming from {segment_4} in my case) I used the {count} tag referenced from segment_4 which did the job. The {count} feature is actually not mentioned in the official docs so i didn't think to try that.